# How to pass values from ScriptDb to Google Sites gadget

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a Google Sites page with an embedded Apps Script gadget. On the page, I want to display ScriptDb data upon clicking a button.

My question is: how can I pass ScriptDb results to the JavaScript embedded in my gadget?

Here is my source:

[Sample-Code.gs]

```
function doGet() {
  // return template page
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Sample-HTML')
      .evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

// assume db contains 10 'records'
function getData(query) {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb(); 
  var data = db.query(query);
  Logger.log(data.getSize()); // returns '10.0'
  return data; // makes showData think this is null
}
```

[Sample-HTML.html]

```
<?!= include('Sample-JavaScript'); ?>

<input type="button" value="show data"
    onclick="google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(showData)
    .getData({})" />
```

[Sample-JavaScript.html]

```
<script>
function showData(db_query_result) {
alert(db_query_result); // returns null.
}
</script>
```

Comment: ScriptDB was deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by `db.query()` is an object as defined in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/script-db-result?hl=fr-FR) that can not be used directly in your UI, you should return the value in a format that can be shown in the page : a string or an array of strings.

I didn't test but this should work :

```
function getData(query) {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb(); 
  var result = db.query(query);
  Logger.log(result.getSize()); // returns '10.0'
  var results = db.query({type: 'person'});
  var data = [];
  while (results.hasNext()) {
   data.push(results.next());
  }
  return data; // data is an array of results
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the guy won't show up anymore.. september '13 ;-)

Comment: A very belated thank you, Serge :) Not quite got the hang of stackoverflow etiquette. It's all water under the bridge now as Google pulled the plug on ScriptDb.

Comment: Thanks (better late than never :-), yes indeed unfortunately..., I sort of liked it ;)